# Probability exercise about SLLN

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\{X_n\}$ be i.i.d random variables. $E[X_1]=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\over n$ converges almost surely to zero.

I know that when the sequence $\{X_n\}$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{Var(X_i)\over i^2} \lt \infty$, the conclusion holds. So I tried to cut $X_n$ to make it satisfy the condition.

Let $Y_n=X_n1_{\{a_n\le X_n\lt b_n\}}$, choose proper $a_n$ and $b_n$ can let $Y_n$ satisfy the condition. I also hope to let $E[Y_n]=0$, but that is hard.

Any advice on this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N \in \mathbb N$ and write $$X_n=X_n1_{\{|X_n|\le N\}}+X_n1_{\{|X_n|>N\}}$$ or in your notation (which however confuses $N$ with $n$) $$X_n=Y_n+X_n1_{\{|X_n|>N\}}$$ So, actually $b_n=N=-a_n$ or to avoid confusion $b_N=N=-a_N$. Now, showing that $EY_n=0$ is not possible, but $$EY_n\to EX_n=0$$ as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: what your say is right. But the problem don't want us to find a sufficient condition but to prove it.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Look here for some help: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/

Comment: To get the convergence of E$Y_n$, we need dominated convergence theorem, but $X_n$ may not be integrable.

Comment: No, $X_n$ are integrable. $EX_n=0$ implies that $E|X_n|<+\infty$ since otherwise $EX_n=\infty-\infty$. Am I wrong?

Comment: If what you say is right, I could apply Kolomogrov SLLN directly. But I remember that Cauchy distribution does have mean.

Comment: No, Cauchy distribution is exactly the case with undefined mean. But ok, I am not sure, If what I say is right.

Comment: You are right. X is integrable. I made a terrible mistake.